# Angular MVC Web API 2 Deploy to remote IIS issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have an application that uses MVC 5, Web API 2, and Angular and I'm having some trouble getting it to work properly. I am using the default MVC routing to initially load the shared layout page, and I'm then using the angular routing to essentially have a single page application. The error I'm getting is the identity impersonate error. (below)

```
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Most likely causes:
system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.
```

I have set the identity impersonate to false, still did not work. I also added the line below to the config file, still did not work.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Here is my Application Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Here is my route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

There is a second part to my question that may be related to the issues I'm facing. I have the application under the default web site in a subfolder (I navigate to server.com/appName). I can get to the home page, but clicking on any links presents the error mentioned above.

Any ideas? Let me know if more code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the application under the default web site in a subfolder (I navigate to server.com/appName).

You need to run ASP.NET (or MVC) inside of an IIS application for it to function. It won't function correctly from a subdirectory of an application.

In Internet Information Services Manager, navigate to the virtual directory, right click it and choose "Add Application". Enter a name, application pool, and the physical path, then click on "OK".

Comment: I may have just poorly described what I am doing here. When I originally created the web application, it appeared as a normal folder under the DefaultWebSite and I then converted it to an application and assigned it an application pool. Is this the same as what you described?